# SAS : add double quotes to words in a variable

Tags: sas

SAS dataset variable has one or more words. I want to add double quotes to each word.

e.g.

```
have1=ABC => need1="ABC"
have1=ABC,XYZ => need1="ABC", "XYZ"
have1=ABC,PQR,KLM => need1="ABC", "PQR", "KLM"
```

I searched around and tried something like this but didn't work

```
need1=cat('"',tranwrd(have1," ",'" "'),'"');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to replace spaces when your words are separated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
s = "ABC        "; output;
s = "ABC,XYZ    "; output;
s = "ABC,PQR,KLM"; output;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   ss = prxchange('s/([A-Z]+)/"$1"/', -1, s);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is

```
need1=cat('"',tranwrd(have1," ",'" "'),'"');
```

That is a correct thinking.All you have to do is simply adding a “,” in it ,and you will solve this problem by yourself.

Try this:

```
need1=cats('"',tranwrd(have1,',','", "'),'"');
```

Comment: Hi Freya! Adding some more context describing what you identified as the issue in the original code and what you changed will help improve the quality of your answers. This will make it more likely to be accepted and will help future users of the site find high quality answers quicker.

Comment: Thank u for your nice reminder!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to replace all occurrences of found words with the words quoted.  If you are not familiar with regex patterns, the capture pattern is inside the parentheses, and the \b indicates a word boundary, .+ means at least one character between the boundaries, and ? means don't be greedy, so don't gobble up other boundaries when matching.  "$1" replaces what was matched with what was matched inside double quotes.

```
data have;
length list $50;
input list;
datalines;
ABC
ABC,XYZ
ABC,PQR,KLM
123,456,789
;

data want;
  set have;
  qlist = prxchange('s/(\b.+?\b)/"$1"/',-1,list); 
  put qlist;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tranwrd` and wrap it in quotes wit `cats`

```
data test;
have1=ABC,PQR,KLM;
want1=cat('"',tranwrd(have1,',','","'),'"');
run;
```